# How to make StringEnumConverter to throw an error when supplied with value not parsable to Enum instead of using default value?

Tags: c#, json, .net, api, json.net

I have a contract in my API:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

public class CustomEmailTemplate
{
    (...)

    [JsonProperty("templateType", Required = Required.Always)]
    public EmailTemplateType TemplateType { get; set; }

    (...)
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public enum EmailTemplateType
{
    Hi,
    Hello,
    Welcome,
}
```

I noticed that when a request contains an invalid name for TemplateType:"Abc" it is automatically converted to a "Hi" value.

How can I make it so that it will throw an error during the deserialization of the request if the unsupported value for TemplateType is passed? I don't want it to automatically use the 1st entry in the enum on invalid input.

Comment: I usually use nullable enums for contracts. And also an enum whose value does not start from zero. public EmailTemplateType? TemplateType { get; set; }....public enum EmailTemplateType
{
    Hi = 1,
    Hello = 2,
    Welcome = 3,
}

Answer (score 1):

Test

```
var json="{\"templateType\":\"Abc\"}";

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomEmailTemplate>(json);
```

result

```
Error converting value "Abc" to type 'EmailTemplateType'. Path 'templateType', line 1, position 21.
```

but there is a more interesting case

```
var json = "{\"templateType\":3}";
```

to throw an error in this case you can add  a JsonConstructor

```
public class CustomEmailTemplate
{
    [JsonProperty("templateType", Required = Required.Always)]
    public EmailTemplateType TemplateType { get; set; }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public CustomEmailTemplate(JToken templateType)
    {
        if (templateType != null)
        {
            if (templateType.Type == JTokenType.Integer)
                if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(EmailTemplateType), (int)templateType))
                    throw new System.Exception("Enum out of range");

            TemplateType = templateType.ToObject<EmailTemplateType>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't throw an error when it is deserialized by the controller. Why it doesn't throw it there.